# How to fetch and rerender the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Please tell me how to fetch new data into the array using useState. **Each time useEffect is using, the array is initialized empty again.** I need to pass this array to the table so that when the values change, the table is rendered again

```
const AccountContainer = () => {
  let [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  let [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  let [accData, setAccData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {loadData()}, [page]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    const data = await response.json();
     data.content.map(acc => {     
       setAccData([...accData, acc])
    });

    setIsLoaded(true);
  };


 return (
          <table data={accData} />
 )
};

export default AccountContainer;
```

added log

```
[]          AccountContainer.js:30
[]          AccountContainer.js:30
[]          AccountContainer.js:30
[]          AccountContainer.js:30
[]          AccountContainer.js:30
[]          AccountContainer.js:30
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-rubin-poywh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks in advance

Comment: this `<table data=accData />` should be `<table data={accData} />`

Comment: Unrelated, but I don't see any reason to wrap loadData in an additional anonymous function.

Comment: can you share `console.log(data)`? and anyhow you don't need to map it, just to spread it - `setAccData(prev => [...prev, ...data])`

Comment: if i just spread it I get 
TypeError: data is not iterable

Comment: you are doing it completely wrong , to push new array , instead of pushing one by one, just do it once like `const data = await response.json(); setAcc([...accData, ...data.content])` that's all.

Comment: @Mashiro it doesn’t work too. Array is still empty

Comment: so if its not working i guess that's because somewhere in your code after this changes make the state empty, please make a codesandbox then i can help you better

Comment: @Mashiro https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-rubin-poywh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @neibti here is the updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-pine-20u6r?file=/src/AccountList.js)

Comment: @Mashiro thank you very much! It works!

Comment: @neibti yourwelcome, ill put it in answer <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-pine-20u6r?file=/src/AccountList.js)

```
// AccountList.jsx
import React from "react";

const AccountList = props => (
  <div>
    {console.warn(props)}
    {props.dataAcc.map(acc => (
      <div>{acc.email}</div>
    ))}
    )
  </div>
);

export default AccountList;
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AccountList from "./AccountList";
import "./styles.css";

const AccountContainer = () => {
  let [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  let [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  let [accData, setAccData] = useState([]);
  const API_URL = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1`;

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, [page]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    const data = await response.json();
    setAccData([...accData, ...data.data]);
    setIsLoaded(true);
  };

  const renderTable = () => {
    if (isLoaded) {
      return (
        <div>
          {console.warn(accData)}
          <AccountList dataAcc={accData} />
        </div>
      );
    } else if (!isLoaded) return "Loading";
  };

  return renderTable();
};

export default AccountContainer;
```